# How to delete directory content in Java?

Tags: java, file-io, delete-directory

After enumerating a directory, I now need to delete all the files.

I used:

```
final File[] files = outputFolder.listFiles();
files.delete();
```

But this hasn't deleted the directory.

Comment: Does it even compile? you are calling delete on array.

Answer (score 138):

You have to do this for each File:

```
public static void deleteFolder(File folder) {
    File[] files = folder.listFiles();
    if(files!=null) { //some JVMs return null for empty dirs
        for(File f: files) {
            if(f.isDirectory()) {
                deleteFolder(f);
            } else {
                f.delete();
            }
        }
    }
    folder.delete();
}
```

Then call

```
deleteFolder(outputFolder);
```

Comment: +1. However, the last line should be `outputFolder.delete()` instead of `output.delete()`.

Comment: I tried it but when I open browser, folder is still here and contains all files...

Comment: Wont work if one of the files is a non empty directory. You have to delete directory contents recursively. if(f.isDirectory())myDelete(f)

Comment: Your're right, changed the code

Comment: I got nullPointerExcpetion  on  for(File f: files) {

Comment: Fixed it: http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29 sometimes returns null

Comment: This deletes `folder` too, which is not wanted in the question. To not delete `folder`, move `folder.delete()` to the end of `if(f.isDirectory()) {..}` block.

Answer (score 112):

To delete folder having files, no need of loops or recursive search. You can directly use:

```
FileUtils.deleteDirectory(<File object of directory>);
```

This function will directory delete the folder and all files in it.

Comment: i guess you mean the commons-io method: org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteDirectory(File)

Comment: Almost there! The question was how to delete the folder's content (not the filter itself) - commons-io has a method for that as well: FileUtils.cleanDirectory(File);

Comment: Is there a similar way to delete only the files inside the folder and not the folder itself??

Comment: @Lucy check the comment above. You can use FileUtils.cleanDirectory(File) method as Daniel has mentioned

Comment: I'm using org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteDirectory(File) but still get "IOException: Unable to delete directory" with no other information.  

The application I am running (locally on MacOS) creates the directory and clones a git repo into it.  When I restart the application, FileUtils.deleteDirectory(File) is called to reset things and that's when I get the error.  The same app that creates the directory cannot delete the directory upon a second startup.  It always runs under my user, which has full access to that directory.

What am I missing?  :)

Answer (score 11):

All files must be delete from the directory before it is deleted.

There are third party libraries that have a lot of common utilities, including ones that does that for you:

- Apache [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) [`FileUtils.forceDelete(..)`](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#forceDelete%28java.io.File%29)
- [guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) [`Files.deleteRecursively(..)`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html#deleteRecursively%28java.io.File%29)

Comment: Unfortunately, [`Files.deleteRecursively()` was removed from Guava](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320376/why-is-files-deletedirectorycontents-deprecated-in-guava) in version 11.0.

Comment: FileUtils.forceDelete()  belongs to commons-io.

Answer (score 8):

You can't delete on an array ! This should work better :

```
for (File f : files) f.delete();
```

But it won't work if the folders are not empty. For this cases, you will need to recursively descend into the folder hierarchy and delete everything. Yes it's a shame Java can't do that by default...

Answer (score 5):

Here is one possible solution to solve the problem without a library :

```
public static boolean delete(File file) {

    File[] flist = null;

    if(file == null){
        return false;
    }

    if (file.isFile()) {
        return file.delete();
    }

    if (!file.isDirectory()) {
        return false;
    }

    flist = file.listFiles();
    if (flist != null && flist.length > 0) {
        for (File f : flist) {
            if (!delete(f)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return file.delete();
}
```

Comment: This code block: "if (!delete(f)) {
                return false;
            }"
could be replaced with "return delete(f);" could it not?

Answer (score 4):

You can't delete an `File` array. As all of the other answers suggest, you must delete each individual file before deleting the folder...

```
final File[] files = outputFolder.listFiles();
for (File f: files) f.delete();
outputFolder.delete();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use FileUtils with FileUtils.deleteDirectory();

Comment: Better mention that `FileUtils` is a part of Apache Commons IO.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(File f : files) {
    f.delete();
}    
files.delete(); // will work
```