# Why is Files.deleteDirectoryContents() deprecated in Guava?

Tags: java, guava, deprecated

In Guava 10+, Google deprecated [Files.deleteDirectoryContents()](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/10.0/api/docs/com/google/common/io/Files.html#deleteDirectoryContents(java.io.File)). JavaDoc says

> Deprecated. This method suffers from poor symlink detection and race
>   conditions. This functionality can be supported suitably only by
>   shelling out to an operating system command such as rm -rf or del /s.
>   This method is scheduled to be removed from Guava in Guava release
>   11.0

I am confused on why there is a race condition. I think having this method is actually useful and find shelling out to operating system a poor solution. Can the authors share why the made this decision?

Comment: To be more clear, I think having a race condition problem isn't a major bug. Many libs, like `ArrayList` are not thread safe or have race conditions. Even `File.remove` has the same issue. But they are all documented. So I was hoping to hear an answer besides what the documentation already says on why they chose to make it deprecated.

Comment: The difference between this race-condition and typical non-thread-safe classes is that there is no "fix" for it.  By contrast, you can solve Java thread-safety issues with non-thread-safe classes by synchronizing on a lock object.  A method that simply cannot do what people expect it to do is a bad method.

Comment: (By "there is no fix", I mean that no fix is possible at the Guava or Java platform level.  It would theoretically be possible to fix this at the operating system level; e.g. if the file system was made ACID transactional.  But don't hold your breath waiting ...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am confused on why there is a race condition.

For example, suppose that one thread calls `Files.deleteDirectoryContents()` and a second thread (or an external process) simultaneously creates a new file in the directory.

When you return from the call, can you rely on the directory being empty?  Nope!

Anyway, if you find the functionality of this method to be useful ... despite its flaws ... you are free to take a copy of the code, tweak it, and embed it in your application.  (Just check the Guava source code license and make sure that you conform to it.)

> Can the authors share why the made this decision?

I think that they already have; see the deprecation notice.  If you want more, try searching the issue tracker and the Guava discussion group.  You could even try asking politely on the discussion group, though if your agenda is to change their minds, I doubt that you will succeed.

Comment: The same would be true for shelling out to the OS, would it not?

Comment: +1 Wouldn't the same be true shelling out to OS. I think if a library is not thread safe then it should be documented and up to the developer to make sure they use it correctly.

Comment: @Stephen C, I am not trying to change any body's mind. I am sure there is a good reason on why this is deprecated. I just thought there was maybe a problem besides race conditions that forced to do this. But there are a lot of libs that have race conditions. I thought maybe there would be a better reason.

Comment: Guava is unusually keen on making it as hard as possible to accidentally screw up something...like race conditions.

Comment: @AmirRaminfar - The authors also list "poor symlink detection" as a reason for deprecation.  I think they are referring to the fact that it is difficult to reliably/portably/cheaply distinguish between a file and a symlink to a file in pure Java.  And you have to for this method.  FWIW - these are very good reasons.  There's no need for a better one IMO.

Comment: @StephenC that seems like a good answer. I would have accepted that if you made than answer. :0

Comment: @AmirRaminfar - I would have, except that you didn't raise it in your question (contrast ... you *did* raise the race condition) and hence I assumed that you understood what they meant about symlink detection.

Comment: @anders - yes it would.  But at least it is not Guava's problem anymore :-)

Answer (score 5):

The race condition is potentially worse than "directory might not be empty," and this is in part because of the poor symlink detection.  Consider this code snippet:

```
// Symbolic links will have different canonical and absolute paths
if (!directory.getCanonicalPath().equals(directory.getAbsolutePath())) {
  return;
}
... delete its contents ...
```

If `directory` is a plain directory during the check but a symlink to `/` afterward, `deleteDirectoryContents` will happily try to wipe the whole filesystem.

Maybe there's a workaround, but we haven't found it.  And making ad hoc fixes for a potential security bug is scary.

Answer (score 1):

For more examples of broken symlink detection, see [these bugs filed by users](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/list?can=1&q=deleteDirectoryContents&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Milestone%20Summary&cells=tiles).

In short, it's impossible to wipe a directory unless you provide the canonical path to that directory.  If `/tmp` is a link to `/some/other/directory`, `deleteDirectoryContents` can't wipe `/tmp/mytempdirectory`.  Maybe there's a possible workaround here, too, but we threw up our hands.

Answer (score 1):

Are you serious? You are trying to solve multithreading operations:

For example, suppose that one thread calls Files.deleteDirectoryContents() and a second thread (or an external process) simultaneously creates a new file in the directory.
When you return from the call, can you rely on the directory being empty? Nope!

And what about another process operates on the directory??? It cannot be solved and you should not handle transactions since it is simply not possible. And argument that somebody makes symlink to root so I delete whole filesystem - should not acccess rights to filesystem handle that? And if you are running such operation as root you should know what you are doing. What about disable deleting files at all in filesystem, it is dangerous!!! I will use different library then if authors of Guava solve such idiotic problems.